# when did the temporary object created by implicit class-type conversion through constructers get destroyed

Tags: c++, constructor, temporary-objects

To make the description more specific, see the code below which comes from C++ Primer 4th edition:

```
class Sales_item {
public:
    Sales_item(const std::string &book = "")
      : isbn(book), units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) {}
    Sales_item(std::istream &is);
    //as before
} 

Sales_item item;
item.same_isbn(cin);
```

The book says that this code implicitly converts *cin* to *Sales_item* through use the constructor function, and the constructor creates a (temporary) *Sales_item* object by reading the standard input.

So, when does the temporary object get destroyed and is it harmful to use the implicit conversion in this situation?

Comment: At some point in time after leaving `Sales_item::same_isbn`. If memory serves, C++ standard is a bit vague about exact moment. Unless you store reference to that object inside `same_isbn` (which you shouldn't do anyway), there are no problems.

Comment: Depends if the function takes an object or reference. If it takes a reference the temporary objects lasts at least until the execution of `same_isbn` ends.

Comment: what is `same_isbn` ? Your code sample should show this

Answer (score 0):

As soon as complete expression where temporary object was created finishes executing. In your case it is after complere execution of the last line. Usually it is not harmful unless you are trying to save pointer/reference to temporary object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!